# WASAPI audio recording device positions - GetBuffer() vs GetPosition()

Tags: c++, audio, wasapi

I am trying to get a precise estimation of audio recording timestamps and got some weird behavior:

1. Initially I assumed I can rely on the position and performance counter returned by [IAudioCaptureClient::GetBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370859(v=vs.85).aspx). I assumed that these timestamps would be monotonically increasing (since if I am getting sequential audio frames in the buffer then the timestamp should always increase by number of samples * clocks per sample), however the timestamp seems to be drifting. After rereading the MSDN comments I was puzzled since the text does not explicitly state if the performance counter is the actual recording time of the first sample or the time that the device returned the index of the first sample for the buffer.
2. After that I wanted to use [IAudioClock::GetPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370889(v=vs.85).aspx). But if I call it each time after a successful call to GetBuffer(), on every second call the performance counter stays the same but the position is updated which seems strange (since the device obviously could not have been recording position n and n + k at the same time). I also saw a [comment](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/media/+/master/audio/win/audio_low_latency_input_win.cc#491) about the timestamp from GetBuffer() being unreliable in Chromium code.

Can anyone give some advice on how to correctly interpret these values?

Comment: You can't assume that the audio driver will update the buffer deterministically.  That is why IAudioClock is available, it gives you real-time info.  The samples you retrieve from the buffer ought to lag behind it, giving you some idea how often the driver updates the buffer.

Comment: @HansPassant ok , this makes sense, I also wanted to rely on the GetPosition() calls, but then, why does it give me same performance counters? I assume I could be calling it too often, but then again, Chromium also seems to call it on each pass.